# Exception in thread "main" Persistence is already in use

Tags: java, multithreading, mqtt, paho

When I run Eclipse and compile my program it works only once, and after the first program execution if I tried to run it again I receive:

`Exception in thread "main" Persistence is already in use`

To solve this issue, I have to close Eclipse and re-open it again, and the same thing happens every time, I can run my program once otherwise, I receive the posted message.

What does that error mean and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

```
client != null
Client is Connected
synchCB->@onSuccess(): Connection Successfull
Client is CONNECTED and Resources will be released.
AsynchCB->@deliveryComplete(): 
MSG: .00088782
Exception in thread "main" Verbindung zu Client ist hergestellt (32100)
    at  
  org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms.close(ClientComms.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.close(MqttAsyncClient.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.close(MqttClient.java:401)
    at com.example.mqtt_java.MainClass.releaseResources(MainClass.java:87)
    at com.example.mqtt_java.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:53)
```

**Code**:

```
client = new MqttClient(serverURI, clientID);
    //client = MQTTClientFactory.newClient(IP, PORT, clientID);

    if (client != null) {
        System.out.println("client is not null");

        //client.setCallback(AsynchCB);
        //IMqttToken token = client.connectWithResult(opts);
        client.connect();
        if (client.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Client is Connected");

            client.publish(TOPIC, "33300".getBytes(), QoS, false);
            client.close();
            client.disconnect();
        }else {
            System.out.println("client is not connected");
        }
    }else {
        System.out.println("client = null");
    }
}
```

**Console_output**:

```
Exception in thread "main" Persistenz wird bereits verwendet (32200)
at   
 rg.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence.open(MqttDefaultFilePersistence.java:112)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:286)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:167)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.<init>(MqttClient.java:224)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.<init>(MqttClient.java:136)
at com.example.mqtt_java.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:47)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are actually shutting down the original version of the program (click the red cross in the console).

You probably have some background (MQTT) threads that have not shutdown so keeping the application running and holding the lock on the persistence directory.

Comment: now after each excution to my program i terminate he consoel and Remove all terminated launches. when i run the prog again it works fine (publish or subscribe), but at the end of the console screen , I always receive the message in the above posted update. kindly please let me know how can i stop receiving it